# Manipulating inventory data

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am working with ansible and I have this an inventory file with a lot of stuff defined.

**`cat inventory.yml`**

```yaml
...
vars:
  host:
    abcserver1:
      url: abcserver1.server.com
      port: 1
    abcserver2:
      url: abcserver2.server.com
      port: 2
    abcserver3:
      url: abcserver3.server.com
      port: 3
    abcdb21:
      url: abcdb21.server.com
      port: 21
    abcdb22:
      url: abcdb22.server.com
      port: 22
    abcdb23:
      url: abcdb23.server.com
      port: 23
    abcdb21b:
      url: abcdb21b.server.com
      port: 21
    abcdb22b:
      url: abcdb22b.server.com
      port: 22
    abcdb23b:
      url: abcdb23b.server.com
     port: 23
```

Now I want to a task with a filter capturing the URLs from the hosts which have "db2" in their URL, and then do a `netcat` to everyone of the (6) using their URL and port.

In this case I want to do a task to run the following commands:

```bash
netcat -zv abcdb21.server.com 21
netcat -zv abcdb22.server.com 22
netcat -zv abcdb23.server.com 23
netcat -zv abcdb21b.server.com 21
netcat -zv abcdb22b.server.com 22
netcat -zv abcdb23b.server.com 23
```

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: I tried this:

```yaml
- name: List
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.value.url}}"
  loop: "{{ host }}"
```

But I am getting this error:

> Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this
> instead:...

I managed this by doing this:

```yaml
- name: Netcats
  shell: nc -zv {{ item.value.url }} {{ item.value.port }}
  loop: "{{ host | dict2items }}"
  when: "'abcdb2' in item.key"
```

Comment: Instead of using `netcat` it is recommended to use Ansible modules, see in example [How to test ... listening server in Ansible?](https://serverfault.com/a/1121379/448950) ...

Comment: I take a look at this. Regarding my question, can help?

Comment: Since you have raised several somehow unrelated questions (it is more a use case description ...) and some of your questions are already answered within a comment with a link, can you provide more information and details to which of your questions do you need help?

Comment: How can I capture all abcdb*.server.com values (urls and ports) ?

Comment: One approach is to use [Patterns: targeting hosts and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html#common-patterns) and [`--limit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html#patterns-and-ansible-playbook-flags).

Comment: My idea was to implement something like this: shell: nc -zv {{ host.abcdb*..url }} {{ host.abcdb*.port }}. Is it possible?

Comment: I edit the question and got errors...

Comment: Your error gives you a hint: `host` is not a list, but instead a dictionary. Also your inventory is not really an inventory but a variables file. Have a look at [Inventory Basics...](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups).

Comment: That's not really the issue. I managed to find the solution and wrote it above

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *netcat* use [*wait_for*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html#ansible-builtin-wait-for-module-waits-for-a-condition-before-continuing). If you have more hosts wait asynchronously. See [*Asynchronous actions and polling*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-actions-and-polling). For example, given the file

```yaml
shell> cat inventory.yml
abcserver1:
  url: test_11
  port: 22

abcdb21:
  url: test_12
  port: 22

abcdb22:
  url: test_13
  port: 22
```

Read the file and create the dictionary

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: inventory.yml
        name: my_hosts
```

gives

```yaml
  my_hosts:
    abcdb21:
      port: 22
      url: test_12
    abcdb22:
      port: 22
      url: test_13
    abcserver1:
      port: 22
      url: test_11
```

Select 'db2' keys and wait for the ports asynchronously

```yaml
    - wait_for:
        host: "{{ item.value.url }}"
        port: "{{ item.value.port }}"
      loop: "{{ my_hosts|dict2items|selectattr('key', 'search', 'db2') }}"
      async: 30
      poll: 0
      register: async_results
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: inventory.yml
        name: my_hosts
    - debug:
        var: my_hosts
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - wait_for:
        host: "{{ item.value.url }}"
        port: "{{ item.value.port }}"
      loop: "{{ my_hosts|dict2items|selectattr('key', 'search', 'db2') }}"
      async: 30
      poll: 0
      register: async_results
    - debug:
        var: async_results
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - async_status:
        jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
      loop: "{{ async_results.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item.key }}"
      register: async_poll_results
      until: async_poll_results.finished
      retries: 30
    - debug:
        var: async_poll_results
      when: debug|d(false)|bool
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [include_vars] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [wait_for] ******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'abcdb21', 'value': {'url': 'test_12', 'port': 22}})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'abcdb22', 'value': {'url': 'test_13', 'port': 22}})

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [async_status] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=abcdb21)
ok: [localhost] => (item=abcdb22)

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Set debug if you want to display the details

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e debug=true
```